# How do you debug Jest Tests?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, debugging, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I can't find any information on debugging my unit tests written with Jest.

How do you debug Jest Tests ?

Comment: I know this is post is aged. However, I wanted to add an update that might be helpful. There now exists a VSC extension simply called [Jest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest). It adds real-time feedback when working in `.test.js` files. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 280):

You do not need `Chrome` for **Jest** tests.

The simplest solution I found is to use **VS Code** `JavaScript Debug Terminal`.

And it works with Typescript and Nrvl.Nx work-spaces out of the box.

1. Open the command palette and start `Debug: JavaScript Debug Terminal`:

[image]

2. Run tests in that terminal in a *Watch mode* `npm test --watch`.
3. Set a break-point in your file.
4. Make any change in a file you want to debug and save.
5. `watch` will run Jest tests against modified files.

When you want to narrow down the number of files run by the --watch, press `p` in the terminal and enter a pattern, which is just a part of the file name you want to test and hit [Enter]

To limit it to a single test in a file - focus it with f, so change it(...) to fit(...)

Comment: perfect..this should be the answer

Comment: I had to use `npm test -- --watch` but otherwise perfect answer!

Comment: thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

Comment: Like @PirateApp mentioned, Jest has a max. default timeout so tests should run within 5s, but we need more than that to debug. We can change this max. timeout on jest.setup.js, but wondering if there's better alternative?

Comment: @PirateApp  I never had a problem with timeout, so it could be something specific to your settings.

Answer (score 45):

You can use Chrome DevTools to debug Jest tests.

**First**, start Node debugger in your project:

```
node --inspect-brk <path to jest.js> --runInBand <path to your test file>
```

Examples:

- If you install Jest locally (Linux example):

  `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand mymodule/test.js`
- If you install Jest globally (Windows example):

  `node --inspect-brk "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\jest\\bin\\jest.js" --runInBand mymodule\\test.js`

**Then**, you can open the Google Chrome browser, and type in the address bar:

```
chrome://inspect
```

Now click the inspect link under "Remote Target" to open Chrome DevTools.

Note that you probably need to add the source code folder to the workspace in chrome-devtools, so as to be able to set breakpoints.

Now you can press F8 to start debugging.

**[FYI]**:

- My Node version: v10.11.0
- My Jest version: 23.6.0
- My Google Chrome version: 71.0.3578.98

---

**[Update]**
Regarding the step of adding the source code folder to the workspace in chrome-devtools (as asked by Sam), it looks like below:

[image]

And then you can open your script files and set the breakpoints:

[image]

You find the simple [demo project on my GitHub repo](https://github.com/yucigou/stackoverflow-ref-projects/tree/master/debug-jest).

Comment: Hi @Yuci, can you explain how to add the source code folder to the workspace in chrome-devtools?

Comment: @SamKahChiin, see my update on adding the source code folder to the workspace in chrome-devtools

Answer (score 15):

As of 2021, check [Debugging in VS Code](https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting#debugging-in-vs-code) from Jest docs. Add the `configurations` below to your `.vscode/launch.json` file.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "--runInBand"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Still, working in 2023 with jest version 29.5

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a blog post on [7 ways to debug Jest tests in terminal](https://pragmaticpineapple.com/7-ways-to-debug-jest-tests-in-terminal/). Here's the fastest way to do it from it.

You can install [ndb](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb), an improved debugging experience for Node.js, enabled by Chrome DevTools, with

```
npm install -g ndb
```

Then you can run:

```
ndb npm run test
```

which will open the DevTools for you and run the tests.

Or you can just put in one command with:

```
npx ndb npm run test
```

and you're good to go. But do check out the [blog post](https://pragmaticpineapple.com/7-ways-to-debug-jest-tests-in-terminal/) where I go into details of different ways to debug Jest tests.

Answer (score 10):

This is my basic config for debugging Jest in VSCode, add to your launch configurations within settings.json

```
"launch" : {
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "args": [
          "-i"
      ],
       "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js", "node_modules",
      ]
    }
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner you can add to your projects to use `debugger;` in your Jest test files:

1. add this script to `package.json`:

```json
  "test:debug": "open -a \"Google Chrome\" chrome://inspect && node --nolazy --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand --colors --verbose",
```

2. run the script within your project:

```bash
yarn test:debug insert/path/to/file
```

3. Now you can use `debugger;` within your test files to trigger [line-of-code breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#debugger) in Google Chrome!

The script has two parts. First, it opens Chrome — to: `chrome://inspect` — and then it will start a Node process (where we can use debugger) that runs a jest file (from node modules) on a specific test file. **As a result, you must have Jest installed in your project dependencies!**

Answer (score 2):

@Yuci answer was perfect for me.

I'm just precising it in case of you're using jest inside local Docker container. You need to precise **--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229**

```
node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 <path to jest.js> --runInBand <path to your test file>
```

Comment: This is a useful answer in that it covers docker and various other remote scenarios but using it haphazardly is a potential security hole. See https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeking an answer, you debug jest with node-inspector. However this is a very slow process (2-5 minutes to debug a single test), and wasn't very useful in actual usage.

I haven't found a better way to debug Jest, however I have seen a lot of people doing the extra work to make jasmine or mocha work with react components. So that may be a more viable option until node-inspector is actually usable.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
node --debug-brk node_modules/.bin/jest
```

in your project directory. It should start the `node` process paused an listening (usually at port 5858) for a debugger. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is an example of a nice graphical debugger for node.js that can be used to connect to the listening node process.

Answer (score 1):

Adding jest configuration would work only if there is only one project. However, if there are multiple projects within its own folder (i.e. rootfolder/project1, rootfolder/project2), running "jest --watchAll --runInBand --coverage" with breakpoint either in the test file or the file under test would be good option

Answer (score 1):

If you're rendering content with a frontend library like `react-testing-library`, you probably need a visual feedback of your test to debug it.

While Jest uses a virtual DOM, [`jest-preview`](https://github.com/nvh95/jest-preview) adds a browser rendering, so you can actually see what your test is doing.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { debug } from 'jest-preview';

describe('App', () => {
  it('should work as expected', () => {
    render(<App />);
    debug();
  });
});
```

And if you're using Vitest, the equivalent library is called [`vitest-preview`](https://www.vitest-preview.com/)

Answer (score 1):

for some cases it might be enough to gather debug logs.
it's possible to activate them with environment variables [as explained in the doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/26.5/debugging)

Linux/MacOS: `export TS_JEST_LOG=ts-jest.log`

Windows: `set TS_JEST_LOG=ts-jest.log`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. We set breakpoints in the test and the code under test if necessary
2. Right-click on the icon next to the name of the test in the test file. In the menu that opens, click on Debug Test.
   [image]

3. After that, the interpreter will start stopping at the places where you have set breakpoints.
Good luck to everyone