# How to debug Jest Tests when using Yarn 2 / Yarn PnP

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg-v2

I'd like to use the `node --debug-brk` feature described in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33247602/5129731) and the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#tests-are-failing-and-you-dont-know-why) to debug in npm/yarn 1 based projects, but `node_modules/` is [not present](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/pnp/) in Yarn 2 / PnP (Plug n Play) based projects, so those instructions won't work for me.

The usual way to [access a binary in yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run#examples) of `yarn run --inspect-brk jest --runInBand` launches a debugging session from the terminal, but when connecting to Chrome's Remote Target inspector  via `chrome://inspect`, we get an error message about being unable to connect to the jest.js binary, since it's a path to a `.zip` file.

```sh
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/Users/MY_USERNAME/PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/.yarn/cache/jest-npm-24.9.0-8ddb425e99-2.zip/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
```

What workarounds are available without downgrading to Yarn 1?

Answer (score 6):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "jest"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Update: the workaround reported below is necessary for Node `12.15` and below. After `12.16.1`, you can use the following command directly:

```sh
yarn run --inspect-brk jest --runInBand
```

The fix which was added to node 12.16.1 is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/30336).

**Archived answer for older versions of Node, 12.15 and below**

One option is to use [`yarn unplug`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/unplug) before using `yarn run`

```
   yarn unplug jest
```

After that, the following works with Jest in Yarn 2 and Chrome's `chrome://inspect`:

```sh
   yarn run --inspect-brk jest --runInBand # any additional jest args
```

A downside of this approach is that you may need to undo the `unplug` before checking in your branch, since it's described as a [short term measure](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/unplug#details) rather than a long term state to leave a dependency in.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `yarn bin` command to accomplish this. I was able to run our jest tests using node and some debugging flag helpers (in a Yarn pnp context) using this command:

```
yarn node --inspect-brk --expose-gc $(yarn bin jest) test --runInBand --silent --logHeapUsage
```

Credit - Found the solution posted in this [jest issues thread](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/3470#issuecomment-924760520).