# Typescript/React unit testing libraries with ability to step through imported functions for debugging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm currently using Jest to unit test my React components and Typescript functions. So far, it's been a big success at reducing regressions and I am happy with the vscode Jest plugin that lets me step through the unit test code to see variable values and steps before the failure.

However, the plugin/Jest (not sure which) doesn't allow me to step through my imported functions/components I'm trying to test; the debugging step-through only works in the unit test file.

For example:

```
// file.tsx (file with functionality I want to test)
export function addOne(x: number) {
  return x + 1; // can't step through this
}
```

```
// file.test.tsx (the test file)
import addOne from './file';

....... test set up......
it('addOne adds to 3 to get 5', () => { // obviously a failing test
   const start = 3; // can only step through this file
   const result = addOne(start); // step into doesn't work here, will skip over to the expect
   expect(result).toBe(5);
});
```

This was obviously a fake example, but I can only step through the steps in `file.test.tsx` and I can't step into the `addOne` function and see what is happening inside it. I can only see what it returns. In order for me to get around this, I had to place console.logs for all the variables in the imported functionality files (file.tsx) and it has been a pain.

Is there a way to configure Jest (or another unit testing library for react/typescript) to be able to step through these imported functions?

Thanks

**Update:**
I should clarify that when I mean I can't step into functions, I also mean that putting breakpoints in file.tsx doesn't work. The debugger does stop at breakpoints in file.test.tsx however, which I find strange I can't simply do the former.

Comment: Do breakpoints work? So far the debugging is limited to vscode, did you try to debug it the regular way?

Comment: @EstusFlask yes I put breakpoints in vscode across various files. The breakpoints work in the unit test files but the imported functions (file.tsx) don't stop code execution and it ignores those breakpoints

Comment: The regular way is without vscode, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247602/how-do-you-debug-jest-tests . It's unknown if the problem is specific to vacode or your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `debugger;` statements supported by Node. It will stop code execution (breakpoint) and open gdb-like prompt that you can debug in using the terminal. You can find more information on [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting) page. It also explains how to enable debugging in VSCode. Also, WebStorm IDE supports running Jest tests from the IDE and using the IDE-defined breakpoints.

Comment: I should clarify that putting breakpoints in file.tsx doesn't stop execution but they do stop when i put them in file.test.tsx. I'm not sure why.